# What does the osmotic pressure do in an electrolytic solution?

Tags: electrochemistry, pressure, osmosis

I have learnt that in an electrochemical cell, the osmotic pressure in the solution hinders the flow of ions from the electrode to the solution, rather some ions may accumulate on the electrode because of this osmotic pressure. As far as I know, osmotic pressure is a measurement of the tendency of the solvent molecule to flow from one solution to another.

My question is, how does this pressure cause the ions in the solution to gather at the electode?

Comment: **Hint:** The electrode has a negligible amount of ions (it's mostly neutral metal) and the solution has a lot of ions. Which way would the ions go?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ions cause what is called osmotic pressure, not the pressure cause the ions to flow. As positive charge accumulates on the electrode, it has a tendency to attract extra negative charge towards itself, as alike attract each other. It starts behaving as the cathode and this phenomenon starts to develop what is called osmotic pressure.